# How to put a delay between failed jobs on listeners

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-queue

I need to set a delay between specific failed jobs **on listeners**.
I know if specify the onption `--delay=5` its works, but I need specific delay on a **listener** (not on standard job). I try put the property `delay` on Listener, but doesn't works.

```
<?php

namespace Froakie\Listeners;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Froakie\Events\ExampleEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

/**
 * Class ExampleListener
 *
 * @package Froakie\Listeners
 * @author Miguel Borges <miguel.borges@edirectinsure.com>
 */
class ExampleListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 5;

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    public $delay = 5;

    public $seconds;

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param \Froakie\Events\ExampleEvent $event
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function handle(ExampleEvent $event)
    {
//        $this->delay(5);
            throw new \Exception('test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You use `release` to delay a retry. Example:

```
public function handle(ExampleEvent $event)
{
    if ($this->attempts() <= $this->tries) {
        try {

            //Try something

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //Try again later
            $this->release($this->delay)
        }
    } else {
        //Force end the job
        $this->delete();
    }
}
```

It should be noted, however, that the value entered is the delay time in seconds. So if you wanted to to delay it by 5 minutes:

```
$this->release(300);
```

Comment: where do I put my code? inside if or did put the if/else inside a try catch and my code inside of try?

Comment: `release` should be called inside the `handle()` function on your job. Structuring the logic is really up to you though. You could put the release in the catch section of a try/catch block if you wanted. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thx. I cannot use ```$this->delete()``` because  it makes manual retry impossible . if I use ```$this->fail()``` method sometimes on manual retry code give me ```MaxAttemptsExceededException``` and I can never successfully run the job from there.